# Downloading Prisma Engine for Windows error. Reason: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, prisma

I installed prisma into my project. I entered this command into my terminal:

```
$ npm install prisma
```

It worked fine and checked my package.json if the prisma is installed.

```
"dependencies": {
...
"prisma": "^4.12.0"
...
}
```

However, when I invoke;

```
npx prisma init
```

it gives me the following error:

Downloading Prisma engines for Node-API for windows [                    ] 0%Error: request to https://binaries.prisma.sh/all_commits/659ef412370fa3b41cd7bf6e94587c1dfb7f67e7/windows/migration-engine.exe.gz.sha256 failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.225.165.109:443

The proxy configuration is set and also works fine with my npm commands.
I also tried to run terminal as administrator and turn-off temporarily my firewall but same error occurs.
Can anybody help me with this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have mistake in package.json file. prisma is under "devDependencies" : {  "prisma": "^4.12.0" }

Comment: Can you try changing your network and check if you get the same error?

Comment: @NurulSundarani I tried it but the same error occurs.

Comment: Can you have a look at solutions mentioned in this GitHub Issue: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2660 ?

Comment: @NurulSundarani, thank you for sharing that link. I actually had read all of the suggested solutions on github and still getting same error after following it. I think it has something to do with my proxy server since I am working behind proxy Although my proxy setting its user name and password are set properly I still getting same error. I just don't know if there are other option. I tried to install prima in my project at home without proxy server and it successfully initiated.

Comment: I too think it might have something to do with your proxy server